# Replace matching values in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe_1 with
 - ID;
 - Name.

```
ID |  Name  |  
231| Jane   |
222| Alex   |  
345| Mary   |
367| Derek  |
```

And dataframe_2 with
 - ID;
 - Name.

```
ID |  Name   |  
231| Samantha|
224| Debora  |  
345| Luis    |
367| Pit     |
```

So that resulting dataframe must look:

```
ID |  Name   |  
231| Samantha|
222| Alex    |  
345| Luis    |
367| Pit     |
```

My goal is to change names in DF1 to names from DF2 by matching IDs and keeping all other.

What did I tried:

```
ass['Name'] = ass['Name'].map(cab.set_index('ID')['Name'])   #got NaN instead Alex

dd = dict(zip(cab.ID,cab.Name)) 
ass = ass.replace({"Name": dd}) #nothing changed
```

But no resuts.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `ID` column and then replace missing values by original values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1['Name'] = df1['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['Name']).fillna(df1['Name'])
print (df1)
    ID     Name
0  231  Samanth
1  222     Alex
2  345     Luis
3  367      Pit
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.where` along with `pd.merge`

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on="id")
df["name"] = np.where(df["name_y"].isnull(), df["name_x"], df["name_y"])
df.drop(["name_x","name_y"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
  id      name
0  231  Samantha
1  222      Alex
2  345      Luis
3  367       Pit
```

Comment: Solution is wrong, try change 2. and 3. row of `df1`

Comment: got ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Comment: @jezrael yeah, in previous solution I was only checking if id is in other dataframe. Corrected it

Comment: @Ison check the Edited answer